# Add an attribute to <a> tag using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image] 
 As depicted in the above image, I am trying to put a tick mark (✓) next to 'a set of particular' visited links (links inside li tags) in [my webpage](https://thomas9.com/).

**JS used in the HTML to insert a 'visited' attribute to <a> tags.**
I placed this code in the footer (after the links are displayed in the screen). This is not working though (I am not seeing the attribute created in the HTML).

```
localStorage.setItem('visited-'+window.location.pathname,true);
var links = document.querySelectorAll('#the-content > ul > li > a');
for (i=0;i<links.length;i++) {   
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.host == window.location.host && localStorage.getItem('visited-' + link.pathname + '/')) {
    link.dataset.visited=true;
  }
}
```

**CSS Code**
I can confirm that this code is working as if I manually create an attribute for the <a> tag, the styling is applied.

```
article .the-content a[data-visited] {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed orange;
}

article .the-content a[data-visited]:after {
  content: ' ✓';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
link.dataset.visited=true;
link.setAttribute('data-visited', 'true');
```

The `dataset` property only manipulates the JavaScript properties but does not impact HTML attributes. More information about the difference can be found in this question: [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, its not working for me yet. Is it something to do with my document selector code snippet?

Comment: @amitz27 Your CSS indicates that `the-content` is a class while your document selector in the JS indicates that `the-content` is an ID. Without seeing the HTML, we can't tell which is correct.

Comment: @rick.attendant.6 - HTML is here -> https://thomas9.com/

Comment: @amitz27 You need to change `#the-content` to `.the-content` in your querySelectorAll

Comment: The + '/' in my code caused the issue. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createAttribute()` for this

just replace

```
link.dataset.visited=true;
```

with

```
let attr = document.createAttribute("data-visited"); // Create a "data-visited" attribute
attr.value = true; // Set the value of the attribute
link.setAttributeNode(attr); // assign attribute node to element
```

to know more about `createAttribute()` check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createattribute.asp)

Update: your 'the-content' used in html is a class not an id
Also replace

```
document.querySelectorAll("#the-content > ul > li > a");
```

with

```
document.querySelectorAll(".the-content > ul > li > a");
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But not working for me yet.

Comment: Thanks @Hemant Malik - I assume your last line of code should be "link.setAttributeNode(attr);". I updated the querySelectorAll as mentioned and still no luck.

Comment: The + '/' in my code caused the issue. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Great! thanks for pointing out that 'attr' issue in the code, i have fixed it now just in case someone copies it.